# DTO and Self Tracking Entities pattern in the entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

- In What scenario that I have to use DTO's pattern in the entity framework the and not the Self Tracking Entities pattern?
- Can I start with Self Tracking Entities because it's easier to develop  and then add DTO's in the next Phase ???

As always, your advice is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this might answer it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335715.aspx

The section on DTOs basically says that you can add DTOs on top of the STEs where needed, to get implement  certain outlier cases where STEs just don't work.